# Is there an image editor like Windows' Paint for OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, software, image-editing

I tried out several image editors mentioned on [this site](http://www.pure-mac.com/graphics.html) but some of them (like [Pixen](http://www.pure-mac.com/graphics.html#pixen) and [Seashore](http://www.pure-mac.com/graphics.html#seashore)) were very disappointing. These apps were too simple and low level.

What do you suggest for a **(preferably free)** image editor on OS X?

P.S: I was using [GIMP](http://www.pure-mac.com/graphics.html#gimp) on Linux and also know that it was released for OS X too, but I want to find new good applications.

Comment: I think this is too subjective as it stands.

Comment: @Chealion I don't think so because I really want some good app, when I was use XP I can do my job only with paint but I can't find such a simple app in os x. it's really strange for me that there is good & free & simple application for editing image in os x!

Comment: @Am1rr: Ug, can't edit to rephrase the question. Try asking for an alternative to GIMP for OS X or a native port of GIMP.

Comment: @Josh it better change to ALternative to paint. because GIMP was not so simple

Comment: @Am1rr3zA It's a lot more useful now instead of just a list of image editing applications question. (Where we could copy and paste from the 2 or 3 that are on Super User)

Comment: Lots of alternatives: http://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-paint/?platform=mac

Comment: You can actually get MS Paint from WineBottler

Answer (score 27):

You could try [Paintbrush](http://paintbrush.sourceforge.net/) (free).
As quoted from its website :

*Paintbrush is a simple paint program for Mac OS X, **reminiscent of Microsoft Paint** and Apple’s own now-defunct MacPaint. It provides users with a means to make simple images quickly, something which has been noticeably absent from the Mac for years.*

[image: paintbrush]

Comment: I said in my question I use Seashore but it's was so bad.

Answer (score 12):

### Acorn ($49 or free with reduced features)

[Acorn](http://flyingmeat.com/acorn/) is what you want.

Comment: I like this one, but it's better if it's also free :P

Comment: Free version info: http://flyingmeat.com/acorn/acornfree.html

"You can use Acorn 2 without paying a single cent. How awesome is that?

Here's how it works: when you first download Acorn, it runs in "trial mode" for a couple of weeks. If you decide not to purchase it after 14 days, the trial will end and Acorn will disable some advanced features, but will continue working for your image editing needs. You can still open images and crop, filter, rotate, add layers, add text, touchup and just have fun with your images. All without paying a single cent, and completely guilt free."

Comment: url for free version is dead

Comment: The link for the free/trial version is now the same as in the answer. There you can find "download trial" to donwload a zip file with the app.

Answer (score 11):

[Pixelmator](http://www.pixelmator.com/) is a great alternative to Photoshop and similar to paint.net on windows

Comment: the Pixelmator problem is that it's not free, it's cost about 50$ i need free one.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify the Free part in your question. it’s not mentioned.

Answer (score 8):

I think it’s too subjective. Anyway, probably the two candidates are:

1) You don’t have Photoshop experience (or want to get far from it): [Acorn](http://flyingmeat.com/acorn/) is for you.

2) You know Photoshop and have some experience with it: [Pixelmator](http://www.pixelmator.com/) will make you feel more at home.

Answer (score 5):

You said that you already know **Gimp**. I use that at times on my Ubuntu box and my Macbook. Also, Seashore on the Mac for really simple stuff.

Here are a couple of links to open source options.

- http://www.osalt.com/graphic-applications
- http://www.opensourcemac.org/

Answer (score 4):

I use [Pixen](http://www.pixenapp.com/) for the lightweight jobs.

Update 2018: Since I recommended it 8 years ago, Pixen is now a paid app. Apparently I'm not the only one who thought they were doing something right. I wish them well with it. In the intervening time, I've gravitated to using Preview for basic photo editing and markup.

Comment: This image appears to have gone dead; would you possibly be able to replace it?

Comment: Sorry, I no longer have the image either.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why nobody talks about [Krita](https://krita.org/en/).
It is free and powerful with a lot of options. I was a real user of Paint.NET and I got sad when I migrated to Mac and didn't get my Paint.NET.  Now I am using [Krita](https://krita.org/en/) and this is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

What about the PowerPoint? You can edit images and then take a screenshot.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. PowerPoint is neither an image editor nor a drawing/painting package, and taking screenshots will only create images at screen resolution.

Comment: Great idea! I had PowerPoint installed and needed this fancy WordArt style! Quick & easy

Answer (score -5):

Yes, macOS comes with a built-in image editor called "Preview," which has basic editing capabilities similar to Windows' Paint. While Preview is primarily used for viewing images and PDFs, it also includes basic image editing features. Here's how you can use Preview for basic image editing on macOS:

Open Image with Preview:

Right-click on the image file.
Choose "Open With" and select "Preview."
Basic Editing Functions:

Crop: Select the Crop icon from the toolbar, and then drag to select the area you want to keep.
Resize: Navigate to the "Tools" menu, select "Adjust Size," and enter new dimensions.
Rotate: Use the Rotate icon in the toolbar to rotate the image left or right.
Annotations:

Add Text: Select the Text icon in the toolbar to add text to the image.
Draw Shapes: Choose the Shapes icon to draw lines, arrows, rectangles, or ovals.
Color Adjustments:

Navigate to the "Tools" menu, select "Adjust Color," and make adjustments to brightness, contrast, saturation, and more.
Export/Save As:

After making edits, go to "File" > "Export" or "File" > "Export as PDF" to save your changes.

While Preview is suitable for basic image editing, if you need more advanced features, you might want to consider third-party image editing software like Adobe Photoshop, Pixelmator, or GIMP, which provide a broader range of tools and capabilities.