# Are there viable and cheaper alternatives to Photoshop?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, adobe-photoshop

Is there any software like Photoshop that can also open .PSD files? I don't need an enterprise / extremely feature laden editor, but I do wish to have the following required features at a price point less than a Photoshop license:

1. Able to crop
2. JPG compression optimization
3. Work with layers
4. Able to open PSD format files
5. Save in PDF format

Comment: If you just want 1,2,4,5 - you can do it on Preview.

Comment: @Sairam You might want to actually answer this since comments can and do get cleared since they are for clarifications as opposed to answers.

Comment: This is a great thread for all software less than PS - and we have another thread covering software with a strong bias to it costing nothing to obtain here - [Is There A Free Photoshop Alternative for Mac OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44527/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you'll find [Pixelmator](http://www.pixelmator.com) a good substitute for Adobe Photoshop. It will do everything on your list and it costs $14.99.

Comment: I see many people that get both Pixelmator and Acorn - so you can also [check out Acorn](http://www.flyingmeat.com/acorn/) if Pixelmator doesn't work for your tastes / requirements.

Answer (score 5):

You can try Gimp
GIMP stands for “GNU image manipulation program”, and it is one of the oldest and most well known alternatives to Photoshop in existence. Although it doesn’t quite have all of them, you’ll find most of the features included in Photoshop somewhere in GIMP. GIMP is cross platform and supported by a large community.

If just having the feature set isn’t enough for you, there is an alternative based on GIMP known as GIMPShop. It’s the same as GIMP, except the layout has been structured as close to Photoshop as possible, so anyone making the transition should still feel right at home.

Answer (score 4):

I see many people that get both Pixelmator and Acorn after trying and deciding GIMP isn't their cup of tea.

In alphabetical order:

- [Acorn](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/acorn-image-editor-for-humans/id402280036?mt=12) - http://www.flyingmeat.com/acorn/
- [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/) - http://www.gimp.org/
- [Pixelmator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pixelmator/id407963104?mt=12) -http://www.pixelmator.com/

All three have serious image manipulation tools like layers, effects, vector drawing tools, advanced selection tools if you'd rather not go down the various versions of Photoshop path. You will be hard pressed to find image tools that don't open and save to .PSD so it's more a price, feature, use case decision since you have several good alternatives above.

Answer (score 2):

Best Answer is Photoline, although it is little hard to get use to but if you are a professional user you get use to it within 2-3 days and they have great tutorial on their site.

I am also a graphic designer from India and Photoshop is too expensive somewhere around 1000USD or 50,000 India Rupees but photoline is Only 60USD or 3,000 India Rupees after using this software for around 1 month I found it can do all the work of photoshop and biggest thing is it support full CMYK and LAB color model and can export JPEG, TIFF in CMYK. One more thing it is very fast in opening of huge files It will take 5-8 Seconds for opening  150MB CMYK Tiff file (Dual Core + 4GB RAM, 64bit OS)

So give this a try

Now about your requirement

1. Yes it is able to crop.
2. JPEG Compression - Yes, and it can also save and open CMYK JPEG.
3. You can work with layers.
4. It can open PSD files with layers.
5. Yes it can export PDF.

PRICE - Somewhere around 60USD and you can download a 30 day limitation free trial from their website www.pl32.com

Answer (score 0):

**Seashore** is an open source image editor for Mac OS X's Cocoa framework. It features gradients, textures and anti-aliasing for both text and brush strokes. It supports multiple layers and alpha channel editing. It is based around the **GIMP's technology** and uses the same native file format.

http://seashore.sourceforge.net/The_Seashore_Project/About.html

Answer (score -1):

For the past year I have used [www.photoshoponlinefree.com](http://www.photoshoponlinefree.com) which is a browser-based, online, Photoshop-style, image manipulation web app.

Comment: My Photoshop file is usually above 100MB. If i upload that file to their server first. it will waste of time.